# Indexed levenstein search

Tags: postgresql

I want to have Full-Text Search without the stemming - it feels like too much of a naive approach.

Essentially, what I want is something like:

```
select *, (
    select avg(levenstein_distance(d, q))
    from split(" ", :query_string) as q, 
         split(" ", content.document) as d
) as search_rank from content
```

I want it to be blazing fast.

I still want to have my queries / documents split by spaces.
Would the `GIN` index on `document` still be relevant?

Is this possible? Would it be blazing fast?

Comment: stemming was invented for a reason, not out of naivety.

Comment: What did you try yourself? Where did you get stuck?